# How to retrieve data from a map inside a particular document of firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The document is user Id and I want to retrieve "Address1"  of a particular user from the map "Address". [image]

```
 private FirebaseFirestore mfirestore;
    DocumentReference docRef;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser user;



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_address);
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();
        docRef = mfirestore.collection("user").document(uid);


    }

   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        if (document.getData().get("Address")!=null){
                            String Address=document.getData().get("Address").toString();
                           
                        }
                       
                    }





                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UserAddress.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I have retrieve the whole "Address" but not able to find a way to get address1 of the user seperately.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that you've attempted so far.  Please be clear where that code is not working the way you expect, or where you are stuck with that code.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have uploaded the code which I have attempted so far and the point where I am getting stuck. Please help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map type document fields show up in Java as type `Map<String, Object>`.  If you are accessing a map, you can simply cast it:

```
Map<String, Object> address = (Map<String, Object>) document.getData().get("Address");
```

Now you can use that map to access its individual fields:

```
String address1 = (String) address.get("Address1");
```

Ideally you should also check the type a nullity of each value before you cast it, or you might throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out . But in this method I am retrieving the whole Address and then taking out Address1 or Address2 from it but is there any way to only retrieve Address1 of particular user  from Address without retrieving the whole Address.

Comment: No, it's not possible.  You must read the entire document to get any of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in Kotlin.

```
db.collection("app-version")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {

                val versionNum = document.get("versionNumber").toString()
                binding.txtAppVersion.text = versionNum


            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->

            Toast.makeText(
                this, "No such document", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
                .show()
        }
```